# Block matrix with optimization variables in CVXPY

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I want to build a block matrix that has the form

```
Q = [[A, B], [C, D]]
```

where each of the blocks `A,B,C,D` are the following matrices:

- `A` is simply 2x2 identity matrix
- `B` is the embdedding of a 2x1 vector `b=(b_1,b_2)` in the diagonal of the identity `B = diag(b_1, b_2)`
- `C` is the transpose of `B`
- `D` is the 2x2 identity myltiplied by some constant `d`, `D = d*A`

My optimization problem is `min d` such that `Q >> 0`, that is PSD condition. **I need help with this problem.**

Confusions:

1. I know how to make a 2x2 identity matrix using Numpy `np.eye(2)`. I am not sure if it makes sense to use it within my matrix `Q`.
2. Furthemore, for `b` I define
   `b = cvxpy.Variable((2,1))`. Then, I can also define its transpose as `b_t = b.T` but how do I make this as a matrix `B` and `C` given there is no outer product? That is, I need to embed the elements of the vector in the diagonal of the matrix.
3. Since `d` is the variable I minimize over I need to define it as `d = cvxpy.Variable(1)`. But then I cannot simply multiply it to the identity matrix in order to have `diag(t,t)` which I call `T = t*np.eye(2)`.

In general I cannot figure out if I need to first define the block matrix `Q` as
`Q = cvxpy.Variable((4,4))` or `Q = cvxpy.Parameter((4,4))` and then having all terms from above use `cvxpy.bmat`to give it the precise form.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, what is your problem ? Moreover, note that the transpose of a diagonal matrix is exactly this matrix, so `C` is in fact equal to `B`...

Comment: In this case yes `B` is the same as `C`. But except for that triviality, I wonder how to define everything. In the list of confusions I explain why I cannot/struggle to perform this task.

Comment: Does `np.block([[A, B], [B.T, D]])` works?

Comment: No, this is one of the problems. The block matrix `Q` must be either `cvxpy.Variable((4,4))` or `cvxpy.Parameter((4,4))` which is definitely not any np type of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a better answer at other than a programming site. However in this case it's straightforword.

Since swapping two rows and (the same) two columns can be done by

```
M -> Q'*M*Q
```

where Q is a permutation matrix (and hence orthogonal), such a transformed matrix will be PSD iff the original is PSD.

If we write

```
M = ( 1  0  b1 0 )
    ( 0  1  0  b2)
    ( b1 0  d  0 )
    ( 0  b2 0  d )
```

and  swap the middle two rows and columns we get

```
M = ( 1  b1 0 0  )
    ( b1 d  0 0  )
    ( 0  0  1 b2 )
    ( 0  0  b2 d )
```

And this matrix will be PSD iff the two blocks on the diagonal are PSD, iff

```
d > max( b1*b1, b2*b2)
```

Comment: This is strictly related to CVXPY package.